# Django: self.model_set not accesible in custom save() function

Tags: django, django-models

I'm trying to make a custom save function that calculates some values and will store them in another Model to which a ManyToMany relationship exists. From what I can understand from the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/), I should have a field_set way of accessing all the related objects. However, when I save here, I get the error `'Game' object has no attribute 'heat_set'`

I don't see what I'm doing wrong here:

```
class Game(models.Model)
    heat = models.ManyToManyField(Heat)
    [...]

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

        for heat in self.heat_set.all():
            [...]
```

Comment: Since the m2m relation is defined in `Game` with `heat = models.ManyToMany...` you just need to use `self.heat.all()`

Comment: @BrianDestura Thanks! Sometimes I just miss the obvious. If you make this reply an answer instead of just a comment, I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: It happens :) alright posted an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the m2m relation is defined in `Game` with `heat = models.ManyToMany(...)`, you just need to use:

```
self.heat.all()
```